# 2007 Jeep Commander left turn signal will not turn off

Tags: electrical, jeep

I made a left turn today and now my left turn signal will not turn off (i.e., the interior arrow is flashing and the exterior front/rear blinkers are flashing).

Here is the current state of things:

- Stalk left: left signal is on
- **Stalk neutral: left signal is on**
- Stalk right: right signal is on

My research shows that the [multi-function switch](http://www.rockauto.com/catalog/moreinfo.php?pk=1193325&cc=1434535) (i.e., the stalk) in this model frequently goes bad and the stuck turn signal is a symptom.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** The previous issue I mentioned regarding the interior lights has resolved itself somehow, but the turn signal issue perists.  I replaced the fuse that controls the turn signals (cavity #16) and that didn't resolve the issue. Now it looks like my last option is to replace the multi-function switch itself.

Comment: It's very strange, but almost all of the questions about this problem that I can find on the Internet talk about the left turn signal in particular coming on.  I have exactly the same problem with my 2006 Commander, but haven't fixed yet.

Comment: I have a 2007 Jeep Commander and my left turn signal is doing the same thing. I found that if I push towards the dash and lift it up towards the right it will stop it but it is a pain in the butt to do that all the time while I’m driving. I just happened to me yesterday. I am glad that I read this, I’m going to order the multifunction switch on Amazon right now
Thank you Is it the headlight and turn signal multifunction switch? It looks like it’s the whole handle, is that right?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the two are related.

Yep, replacing the "multi-function switch" should take care of your turn signal issue. The interior-light issue would be a completely different, electronic, problem... and may be very difficult to track down.

Comment: Thanks @TDHofstetter. The local parts store wanted $140+ tax. I've ordered the multi-function switch from Amazon for $54 and it'll be here faster! I'll report back to let you know if this fixes it.

Comment: Replacing the multi-function switch did the trick. Was a super easy job, too.